# Move Imageview circular

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to code an app, where I'm able to move an Imageview only on a specific circular path.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    float touchedX = 0;
    float touchedY = 0;
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:  

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            touchedX = event.getX();
            touchedY = event.getY();
            float deltaX = touchedX-widthHalf;
            float deltaY = touchedY-heightHalf;
            double angle = Math.atan(deltaY/deltaX);                        
            timeCircleButton.setX(widthHalf + ((float)(radius*(Math.cos(angle)))));
            timeCircleButton.setY(heightHalf + ((float)(radius*(Math.sin(angle)))));


            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is my onTouchListener so far. HeightHalf and WidthHalf are the Coord. of the center point. I think my idea is right, but right now the ImageView is moving on a part of the circle and not on the whole circle like I want to.

So my question: Where is my fault?

If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: did you read Math. atan docs?

Comment: not directly. But I've tried with radians instead of degrees,too.

Comment: Check again my answer. I uploaded a small complete app on github with an ImageView moving around a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem is that the arctan function values are in `(-pi/2, pi/2)`

This is a mathematical problem, the java implementation follows the maths. The tangent function is by default not invertible, but it can be inverted if you restrict the domain to `(-pi/2, pi/2)`. Therefore the inverse function arctan will only gives back values in `(-pi/2, pi/2)`. The java implementation `atan` pushes this idea further defining this method also at +/-infinity (which mathematically aren't real numbers). As a result you see your `ImageView` moving only on the right-hand side of the circle.

**Solution**: use `Math.hypot()` to calculate the hypotenuse then calculate sine and cosine by divisions.

```
touchedX = event.getX();
touchedY = event.getY();

double deltaX = touchedX - widthHalf;
double deltaY = touchedY - heightHalf;
double hypot = Math.hypot(deltaX, deltaY);
double cosine = deltaX / hypot;
double sine = deltaY / hypot;  

timeCircleButton.setX((float)(widthHalf + radius * cosine));
timeCircleButton.setY((float)(heightHalf + radius * sine)));
```

**EDIT**: I coded up a small example with this code and it works. You can find it [here](https://github.com/gilvegliach/StackOverflowAnswers/tree/master/GoingRoundImageView).

Comment: yes, you're right. But I actually don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Yes, sure, check the code out. Mathematically, in each triangle, sine = (opposide side)/hypotenuse  and cosine = (adjacent side) / hypotenuse, where 'opposite' and 'adjacent' are wrt to the angle you're calculating the sine/cosine

Comment: Well, it seems that you're right -I understand your solution. But it does not work. The ImageView is moving on the cirlce path, but I can't do a turn

Comment: What do you mean with a turn? Explain exactly what is the problem with this code, unfortunately I cannot run it as it is

Comment: @Billabong why dont you just use Math.atan2 ?

Comment: @pskink I never used atan2, but that is a good point. Anyhow, I believe a hypot (2 multiplication, 1 addition, 1 sqrt) plus 2 divisions will be slightly faster than atan2 (a change of coordinates implemented natively)

Comment: I mean that the ImageView is still moving on a part of the circle. But this time it's the half of it. And sometimes it's "flashing" from one side to the opposite side of the circle (maybe + and - changing quickly)

Comment: The image follows your finger. It will be placed on an imaginary line connecting the finger and the center. On this line, the image will be placed at exactly radius distance from the center (towards the finger). Check out my code on github, it does exactly that. This is the logic you look like you're after. If it is different, please explain.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. No, your code is doing the thing right. I found my fault in my code. I had an issue with the current position of the imageview (I just copy and paste your code quickly). THANK YOU!

Comment: I found another problem. You use OnTouchEvent(). Now I'm using fragments for my app there is no ontouchevent method now and a OnTouchListener() isn't working (The ImageView is just moving on a part again).....

Comment: The policy of stackoverflow is to ask another question in these cases, so do so. Anyway, you could add a TouchListener to the ViewGroup containing your ImageView and implement a similar logic. Or you could  still implement onTouchEvent() in your Activity. There are many possibilities, ask another question and people will tell you.